# Run a python script in GO

Tags: go

Is it possible to run a python script in the go programming language? I want to be able to have a go program written, and in the beginning of it, execute a python script, then run the rest of the go program.

Comment: [os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)?

Comment: Yes. It might be more useful to know why you're asking, because why would you *not* be able to execute a python script from a Go program?

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't be able to do it. I've never done it. I don't know how to execute another script within Go. thanks for os/exec I will look into that bereal.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. http://go-lang.cat-v.org/library-bindings

I really don't see any value to using bindings, you may use while migrating your application to keep step by step migration.

In anyways when you want to use any scripting or other languages you can simply execute on the OS and can get the results like @bereal said.